# Process Variable inside ng-if not instancied

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, camunda

i'm using camunda 7.2
In my process i have two user tasks (the first one a simple form to insert data, and the second one to show the same form readonly).
I'm using embedded forms.
I have the following form but i have a problem: using the ng-if directive i don't able to instantiate process variable, while if i use ng-show it works.

```
<form role="form" name="form" cam-form class="form-horizontal">
```

```
 <div ng-if="typeRequest == 'firstCase'">
    <h4 class="text-center">title</h4>

    <!-- Oggetto -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="oggetto" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Oggetto:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oggetto" cam-variable-name="oggetto" cam-variable-type="String" required="required">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Nota descrittiva -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="notadescrittiva" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nota descrittiva:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="notadescrittiva" cam-variable-name="notaDescrittiva" cam-variable-type="String"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Data -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Data:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data" cam-variable-name="data" cam-variable-type="String" required="required">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Indirizzo -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="indirizzorichiesta" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Indirizzo:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indirizzorichiesta" cam-variable-name="indirizzo" cam-variable-type="String" required="required">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Please, any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you put `{{typeRequest}}`, what it shows?

Comment: hi show me exactly the string "firstCase"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because `ng-if` does not renders anything in the DOM.
You probably should use `ng-show` instead.

Comment: but the expression ng-if is true